# Scala code not compiling in SBT - Eclipse Maven build

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to compile sample Spark scala file through sbt and have built maven project in Eclipse IDE

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGBxi.png)

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object simpleSpark {
  def main(args : Arrayt[String]){

    val logfile = "C:\\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\README.md"
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
    val numHadoops = logData.filter(line => line.contains("Hadoop")).count()
    val numSparks = logData.filer(line => line.contains("Spark")).count()
    println("Lines with Hadoop: %s, Lines with Spark: %s".format(numHadoops, numHadoops))
    }
}
```

Comment: The error in the image shows a different line of code than you have in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The error says you have illegal start of expression here set("spark.executor.memory",) . Are you sure you set spark.executor.memory correctly in actual code ?
If yes , can you show what you wrote is .sbt file ?

Comment: Thank you for the help. It got resolved when I changed the syntax as per Scala 2.11.8 version